# Form styling in Firefox vs. Chrome

Tags: css, forms, firefox, google-chrome

I am trying to get this registration form to look consistent across all of the major browsers, or at least Firefox and Chrome.

http://www.lukaspleva.com/MoneyThink/new_mentor_application.html

It looks GREAT in Chrome, especially as far as the spacing between all of the input fields is concerned (it's equal). In Firefox, though, the spacing/padding is kind of all over the place.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: After getting your answer, it would be great to include the problem in this question, so that in the future someone may have the same problem. Otherwise, the moderators may close this question as too localized.

Comment: it's almost same regarding you are talking about styling please add some style in order to look same in all browser as every browser has own set style theme..

Comment: I see the same behavior in FF vs Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You already have each input/label in td-s, so either give td-s widths (if the input is 100px wide, make its td 120px wide), either increase the table's cellspacing property. However, using tables for layout is not recommended. Use CSS floats and padding/margins instead.

Comment: Appreciate the advice. To clarify, I always hear people say that one should use CSS instead of tables...why is that, exactly?

Comment: Because you can swap a CSS file and get a different design (e.g. for theming). It's called separation of content and presentation. Also with CSS you get more power (manipulate many elements with one line).

Comment: The reason why tables even got used as layout is that earlier browsers didn't support floats reliably and with tables, it was easier to make sidebars, paddings with td-s, etc. But now you can write any layout with divs and CSS that will work on any browser including IE6, so tables now should be used what they were originally intended for - to display tabular data.

Comment: You can see on this link how simply swapping one CSS file will give your site completely different view: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/stylesheetswitcher.htm